# Can MySQL 5.7 log queries that would violate sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

As part of a migration to MySQL 5.7 i'd like to find out which queries would fail with the default `sql_mode` that includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

The easiest shortcut would be just to relax the configuration and set:

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

But instead I'd like to modify the application code and address the root cause.

thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I would guess that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is the most likely to trip you up.  Once you understand what it means, it is pretty easy to spot which queries are 'bad'.